# Reconfiguring NServiceBus Loses Messages

Tags: nservicebus

This is my first post on StackOverflow.

I am trying to put NServiceBus behind an interface that looks like the following:

```
interface IMessagingService
{
    IObserver<T> RegisterPublication<T>() where T : IPublishedMessage;
    IObservable<T> RegisterSubscription<T>() where T : IPublishedMessage;
}
```

In order to support this interface without forcing users to have an explictit Start() call, I need to reconfigure the bus each time RegisterSubscription is invoked with a call to a method that looks like this:

```
IBus ConfigureBus()
{
    Configure config = BuildConfiguration();
    return config.CreateBus().Start();
}
```

I can't copy and paste the real code, but hopefully you can see that I need to have a started bus to listen for messages once RegisterSubscription is invoked. I need to add subscribers on subsequent invocations.

The problem that I am running into is that each call to ConfigureBus() seems to be spinning up more threads and results in messages being lost. My handler instances are not invoked, yet NServiceBus logs that it finished handling each of the messages.
With four calls to RegisterSubscription, I lose about 40% of my messages.

Is there a safe way to reconfigure and restart the IBus on the fly without causing this problem? The IBus.Subscribe doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

@bsf's answer

I found a solution. `CreateBus()` returns an `IStarableBus`. If I keep a static reference to that and dispose it before my next call to `CreateBus()`, everything seems to work fine.